# Ignore different files format from stage select in Snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-stage

I have a stage in Snowflake which refers to a S3 bucket with other files than JSON (HTML too).

When I select from this stage I get this error:

```
SELECT s.$1 FROM @RAW.DEV.STAGE_LOCAL (file_format => 'JSON') AS s
```

Error:

```
SQL Error [100069] [22P02]: Error parsing JSON: invalid character outside of a string: '<'
  File 'local/2023-04-10-16/htmlreport.html', line 1, character 1
  Row 0, column $1
```

because it's reading the HTML and JSON files.

Is there some way to ignore those HTML files in the selection?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [PATTERN](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-stage#optional-parameters):

> PATTERN => 'regex_pattern'
>
> A regular expression pattern string, enclosed in single quotes, specifying the file names and/or paths on the external stage to match.
>
> For the best performance, try to avoid applying patterns that filter on a large number of files.

```
SELECT s.$1 
FROM @RAW.DEV.STAGE_LOCAL (file_format => 'JSON', PATTERN => '.*[.]json') AS s
```